# How do I predict how a chart will trend

Tags: javascript, web, math, statistics

I'm working on a JS project where the user draws a graph while the code tries to predict how it will unfold. Does anyone have any ideas how I might be able to accomplish this? Thanks for the help!

[image: picture of my program with what I want the computer to predict]

Comment: Extrapolation is a dangerous thing.  It'd be a good idea to articulate how you'll generate that future curve.  Better to include min/max error bounds to make clear that that is a likelihood, not certainty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different machine learning for time series predictions like Facebook prophet https://facebook.github.io/prophet/